# How to get an InputStream from a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio

How can I get an InputStream from a BufferedImage object? I tried this but ImageIO.createImageInputStream() always returns NULL

```
BufferedImage bigImage = GraphicsUtilities.createThumbnail(ImageIO.read(file), 300);
ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bigImage);
```

The image thumbnail is being correctly generated since I can paint *bigImage* to a *JPanel* with success.

Comment: Similar: [*How to convert BufferedImage to InputStream?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4251383/642706)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying to save the image to a file try:

```
ImageIO.write(thumb, "jpeg", new File(....));
```

If you just want at the bytes try doing the write call but pass it a ByteArrayOutputStream which you can then get the byte array out of and do with it what you want.

Comment: Thanks, writing to ByteArrayOutputStream and then converting it to a ByteArrayInputStream did the job. But I'm wondering why ImageIO.createImageInputStream() didn't work.

Comment: It looks like that expects the Object passed in to be a File (or perhaps other things).  I haven't used the API before... and not sure what it is you are trying to do :-) (consider it a lucky guess on my part that what I gave you worked :-)

Comment: I'm trying to upload the image to a server, that's why I want to create an InputStream from it.

Comment: Ah, look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream(java.lang.Object) input - an Object to be used as an input source, such as a File, readable RandomAccessFile, or InputStream.

Answer (score 98):

From http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2010/01/inputstream-from-url-bufferedimage.html

It works very fine!

> Here is how you can make an
>   InputStream for a BufferedImage:
>
> ```
> URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif");
> BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
> ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> ImageIO.write(image, "gif", os);
> InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
> ```

Comment: Felipe. I was trying to find the type(gif, png, jpg, etc) of an image that came from a URL without an extension. I found a work around for it but when you write the image to an input stream ImageIO.write(image,'gif',os); you have already mentioned the image type, how can I do that without specifying the image type.

Comment: You have to specify a type. I guess it shoulnd't be the same as the input. You can read from a PNG and write on a JPEG.

Comment: Won't this duplicate the data not just once but twice? First when ImageIO.write writes it to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then again when toByteArray() is called. This is not just a memory hit but also CPU hit.

Comment: @morpheus what you say makes sense, so then what is the actual sensible approach ?

Answer (score 8):

By overriding the method `toByteArray()`, returning the `buf` itself (not copying), you can avoid memory related problems. This will share the same array, not creating another of the correct size. The important thing is to use the `size()` method in order to control the number of valid bytes into the array.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    @Override
    public synchronized byte[] toByteArray() {
        return this.buf;
    }
};
ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
return new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.size());
```

Comment: Doing this and using `IOUtils.copy(is, output)` the `buf` results in double size. So it seems a very bad approach. I should downvote but I can't anymore.