# How to convert BufferedImage to InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedimage

I am uploading images using servlet. To perform resize operations i am converting InputStream to BufferedImage. Now i want to save it in mongoDB. Since, i am new to mongoDB as far as i know, GridFS takes InputStream.

So, is there any way to convert BufferedImage to InputStream?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to save the BufferedImage to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) using the [`ImageIO` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html), then create a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) from `toByteArray()`.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Doesn't this load an extra (large) byte array into memory?

Comment: +1. and this method copies the data not once but twice! once when writing to ByteArrayOutputStream and then again by converting it into a byte array when toByteArray() is called.

Comment: You can find the code [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569243/1097600)

Answer (score 26):

## `BufferedImage` ➙ `ByteArrayOutputStream` ➙ `byte[]` ➙ `ByteArrayInputStream`

Use the [`ImageIO.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.OutputStream)) method to make a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) (which is a [`RenderedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html)) into a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). From there get a byte array (`byte[]`), feeding that into an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) of type [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(buffImage, "jpeg", os);                          // Passing: ​(RenderedImage im, String formatName, OutputStream output)
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
```

Both the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `InputStream` implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So you can conveniently have those closed automatically by using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax.

Comment: Have you made the import correctly. The constructor is correct. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])

Comment: Doesn't anything need to be closed anywhere? I'm not asking to be mean, I simply dont know ;)

Comment: @Nicofisi Both `ByteArrayOutputStream` & `InputStream` implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to conveniently and automatically close those resources whether or not exceptions are thrown.

Comment: "Closing a ByteArrayInputStream/ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect." -- comment of two classes' close() methods 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

Answer (score 13):

First of all you must get your "bytes":

```
byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)(bufferedImage).getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

And then use **ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] buf)** constructor to create your InputStream;

Comment: It's funny that this code snippet works much more efficiently than the approved one, although not as elegant

Comment: But it is worth noting that this will only work with images where byte[] is used to represent each pixel

Answer (score 4):

By overriding the method `toByteArray()`, returning the `buf` itself (not copying), you can avoid memory related problems. This will share the same array, and not creating another of the correct size. The important thing is to use the `size()` method in order to control the number of valid bytes into the array.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    @Override
    public synchronized byte[] toByteArray() {
        return this.buf;
    }
};
ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
return new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.size());
```