# Error when trying to save image in PostgreSQL - syntax error at or near "\" at character 823

Tags: java, image, postgresql, jsp, bytea

I am trying to save an image to PostgreSQL with byte data type. I am using JSP to convert image -> bytes according to the documentation. All syntax in Java is correct but when I execute

`ps.executeUpdate();`

PostgreSQL returns

`syntax error at or near "\" at character 823`

> at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:94)
>       at org.postgresql.Connection.ExecSQL(Connection.java:398)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Statement.execute(Statement.java:130)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:73)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:113)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
>       at obj.util.Imagen.addImage(Imagen.java:86)
>       at obj.util.FileUploadHandler.doPost(FileUploadHandler.java:44)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My code is:

```
  File img = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name);
  byte [] byteImage = ImageToByte(img);
  //Conexion
  java.sql.Connection conDot11q     = null;

  Conectar c                        = new Conectar();
  conDot11q                         = c.conDot11qPostgres();
  addImage(byteImage, conDot11q);
```

And the methods:

```
public static byte [] ImageToByte(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);      
           // System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

 return bytes; 
}

public void addImage(byte[] img, Connection conn) {
    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO IMAGENES (IMAGEN, DESCRIPCION) VALUES (?, ?)");
        ps.setBytes(1, img);
        ps.setString(2, "Test");

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried everything without success. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you said you have tried everything. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: examples:
[save images - postgres](http://jeebestpractices.blogspot.mx/2011/03/save-images-into-database-postgres-with.html),
[java converting an image to an input stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853910/java-converting-an-image-to-an-input-stream-without-creating-a-file),
[image from postgresql bytea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078525/displaying-image-from-postgresql-database-bytea),
[webdocs](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~yuan/servlets/UploadImage.java),
[guardar y leer imagenes en postgressql](http://www.jc-mouse.net/base-de-datos/guardar-y-leer-imagenes-en-postgressql)