# type mismatch; found : java.awt.image.BufferedImage required: java.io.File

Tags: java, image, scala, amazon-web-services, io

I am able to resize the image:

```
def resize(is: java.io.InputStream, maxWidth: Int, maxHeight: Int): List[(BufferedImage, S)] = {
 val originalImage = ImageIO.read(is)
 val scaledBI = new BufferedImage(maxWidth, maxHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
 val g = scaledBI.createGraphics
 g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src)
 g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight, null);
 g.dispose
 List((scaledBI, maxWidth.toString() + "x" + maxHeight.toString()))
} //end resize


request.body.files.map { img =>
 val image = resize(new FileInputStream(img.ref.file), 120, 120)
}
```

But I am not able to save this to AWS S3
because:

```
amazonS3Client.putObject("path", "image.jpg",image(0)._1)
```

giving me the error:

```
type mismatch; found : java.awt.image.BufferedImage required: java.io.File
```

I am using Scala 2.10 with playframework 2.2

Comment: Why do  you expect it to work, if you're passing a BufferedImage to something that expects a File? In other words,  it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Looks like you need to convert your BufferedImage to an InputStream (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251383/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-inputstream) then write it with putObject, using the PutObjectRequest constructor that takes an input streaa.